# Where does the DataExtract output go?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm using a [DataExtract](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/) to [pull large amounts of data from ExactTarget](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124257/what-python-library-is-recommended-for-pulling-large-amounts-of-data). However, when I execute "Create", the end result never appears in the FTP directory. I DO see a temporary folder, created at the root of the FTP directory, and can monitor files being populated with increasing size. However, when it completes, this temporary folder gets deleted, and the end result never seems to appear anywhere. (I did see it appear once on a recent previous attempt, but no longer see it, and can't explain this behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They go to a hidden location called the [Safehouse](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/file_transfer_location/).  You'll need to do an Upload [File Transfer Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) on the file to transfer it to the SFTP Export folder.

Comment: Is there any way i can see whats inside the safehouse? Can i access it with read only rigths / or full rights with an SFTP client like filezilla?